# how to solve problem of a stranger characters when i scrape website in Arabic?

Tags: c#

I would like to scrape this site: https://haraj.com.sa

but when I do I get characters like these [stranger character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRS10.png)

I tried these things but don't work for me:

```
string str = "مكاتب ادارية للإيجار";

var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);

dataGridView.Rows.Add( Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes) );
```

Comment: Why it isn't work? If you got an exception, please provide it us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you see strange characters is due to the difference in encoding.

> From MSDN:
>
> Encoding is the process of transforming a set of Unicode characters
>   into a sequence of bytes

---

Additionally when you are webscraping, you can do:

```
string url = @"https://haraj.com.sa/";
WebClient client = new WebClient { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };
string html = client.DownloadString(url);
```

**References:**

[What every developer need to know about encoding character](https://www.windwardstudios.com/blog/what-every-developer-should-know-about-character-encoding)

Answer (score 4):

You should try with Unicode for such conversions.

```
string str = "مكاتب ادارية للإيجار";

var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);

dataGridView.Rows.Add( Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes) );
```

It's much safer in your case as [.Net strings are always as Unicode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding), so you are basically convertring UTF-16 to UTF-8 which could cause the problem. Let me know if this works for you.